# Set the SOAP:Location in WSDL

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a simple Spring/JAX-WS that is annotated simply with the @WebService.

My bean definition looks like this:

```
  <jaxws:endpoint id="secureTest"
  implementor="com.xxx.SessionServiceImpl"
  address="/SessionService">
  ....
    <jaxws:properties>
        ....
    </jaxws:properties>
 </jaxws:endpoint>
```

The problem is that the WSDL generated has soap:address beginning with http:// and I need it to be https://

Now the kicker is that I do not have access to the code at all.  This MUST be done in the bean definition xml file.

Is there a jaxws property that I can set to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Comment this line in:

server/{instance}/deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml

```
<property name="webServiceHost">${jboss.bind.address}</property>
```

This way the soap:address is modified.

Comment: Don't see how that applies as I am not using jboss.  Are you saying I should add a <entry> with webServiveHost as name and address as value?

Comment: Hello. Are you using weblgic server?